# PHP die() before and after

Tags: php, code-cleanup, die

i would like do delete everything on the page and `echo` just the `die()`

Example:

```
Code here!!
<?php $query_area = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblcargos WHERE id_tblarea = '$id_tblarea'") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
More code here
```

So, if the code die, will delete everything after and before die function and `echo` just the `die()`

Comment: Look into output buffering

Comment: Don't look into output buffering if you don't know what it is. This opens some bad doors

Comment: Have all of your PHP processing done before anything gets displayed to the user. If you end up having an error somewhere, you can handle the output much easier.

Comment: Ideally you should not be executing MySQL mid stream, make all of  your data calls and computations before you even start outputting html, you should look into the MVC software pattern

Comment: Rolled back the edit because `//` is unlikely to be a valid escape sequence in what surrounds `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Die()` ends the page. That's the whole point of that function :) You don't want to alter that functionality.

A method you cán do (note the end):

```
$query_area = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblcargos") or myCustomFunction();
```

`myCustomFunction()` can handle the error any way you like. In fact, I'd strongly recommend doing that in favor of `die()`.
You could make it so it shows a 'nice' error page, explaining the user what just happend.

Comment: Thanks, it is a great ideia!! :-) .. i've up your vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *very* basic example of using output buffering:

```
ob_start();
// more code here
$query_area = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblcargos WHERE id_tblarea = '$id_tblarea'");
if (!query_area) {
     ob_clean();
     die(mysql_error()); 
}
//More code here
ob_end_flush();
```

This will capture your page's output and display it normally unless you run into an error. Then it will discard the output so far and only output your error message.

Output buffering can get complicated so I would instead recommend restructuring your code so no content is output until after your PHP logic has completed.

Comment: You'd have my upvote if your whole answer was just the last paragraph. I feel like people who don't know what they're doing often abuse output buffering, and it's taught as a dirty workaround more often than it is used properly. There's certainly no need for it in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the help ;) .. I really enjoy it! But the @Martijn ideia it is better to me, and will work perfectly